# How can I generalize this in-place Selection Sort?

Tags: haskell

Below is an implementation of a selection sort in the `ST` Monad. The input array is copied to a `STUArray s Int Int` with `thaw`, then the copy is sorted in-place.

```
selectionSort :: UArray Int Int -> UArray Int Int
selectionSort arr = runSTUArray $ do
  let (l, n) = bounds arr
  a <- thaw arr
  forM_ [l..n] $ \i -> do
    minIdx <- newSTRef i
    forM_ [i..n] $ \j -> do
      currentMin <- readSTRef minIdx
      jVal <- readArray a j
      minVal <- readArray a currentMin
      when (jVal < minVal) (writeSTRef minIdx j)
    currentMin <- readSTRef minIdx
    iVal <- readArray a i
    minVal <- readArray a currentMin
    writeArray a i minVal
    writeArray a currentMin iVal
  return a
```

Using `FlexibleContexts`, I would like to generalize the type to:

```
(IArray UArray a, Ord a, Ix i, Enum i) => UArray i a -> UArray i a
```

However, this causes the following type error:

```
Could not deduce (MArray (STUArray s) a (ST s))
  arising from a use of `thaw'
from the context (IArray UArray a, Ord a, Ix i, Enum i)
```

How can I change the constraints of `selectionSort` to allow this generalization?

Comment: What if you just add the constraint it says is missing?

Comment: The type of `s` is ambiguous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class API for `array` unfortunately doesn't properly hide the `s` state parameter. When you write `runSTUArray action`, the `action` takes as input an `s` type parameter. In the type annotation for `selectionSort` we would have to write `MArray (STUArray s) a (ST s)`, but this isn't meaningful, since the `s` parameter used inside the runned action isn't even in scope here. Mentioning `s` here just introduces a new different `s` parameter, hence the ambiguity error.

The [`constraint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.8) package has a nice solution for this sort of thing. With `Forall` from [`Data.Constraint.Forall`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.8/docs/Data-Constraint-Forall.html) we can express that a constraint has to hold for an arbitrary choice for a type parameter. In our case, we can express that `MArray (STUArray s) a (ST s)` has to hold for arbitrary `s`, and inside the `ST` action we can instantiate the quantified constraint to the specific `s` that we need.

```
{-# language UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.STRef
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST.Strict
import Data.Constraint.Forall
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Proxy
```

First, we have to create a wrapper class that we can plug into `Forall`.

```
class    (MArray (STUArray s) a (ST s)) => MArray' a s
instance (MArray (STUArray s) a (ST s)) => MArray' a s
```

Now `Forall (MArray' a)` becomes a constraint from which we can generate `MArray' a s` constraints for arbitrary `s`, and `MArray' a s` implies by superclassing the `MArray (STUArray s) a (ST s)` constraint (which we actually need).

For convenience we need an alternate runner function which makes the `s` input type parameter more explicit, so we can refer to it in the body:

```
runSTUArray' :: (forall s. Proxy s -> ST s (STUArray s i e)) -> UArray i e
runSTUArray' f = runSTUArray (f Proxy)
```

The general `selectionSort` can be written now, and we observe that it can be specialized to the previous type:

```
selectionSort ::
  forall i a.
  (IArray UArray a, Ord a, Ix i, Enum i, Forall (MArray' a))
  => UArray i a -> UArray i a
selectionSort arr = runSTUArray' $ \(s :: Proxy s) -> do
  let (l, n) = bounds arr

  -- we use "inst" and a type annotation on its result to instantiate
  -- the Forall constraint to the current "s"
  case inst of
    (Sub (Dict :: Dict (MArray' a s))) -> do

      a <- thaw arr
      forM_ [l..n] $ \i -> do
        minIdx <- newSTRef i
        forM_ [i..n] $ \j -> do
          currentMin <- readSTRef minIdx
          jVal <- readArray a j
          minVal <- readArray a currentMin
          when (jVal < minVal) (writeSTRef minIdx j)
        currentMin <- readSTRef minIdx
        iVal <- readArray a i
        minVal <- readArray a currentMin
        writeArray a i minVal
        writeArray a currentMin iVal
      return a

selectionSort' :: UArray Int Int -> UArray Int Int
selectionSort' = selectionSort
```